# ant - tokenise string into substrings using regex

Tags: regex, string, ant, split, tokenize

I have an input string of the format `abc;def;ghi;jkl;........` and so on. the smallest allowed input string is `abc`, while there is no limit on max number of tokens. Also the length of each token is NOT fixed to 3. it can be any number of characters.

for eg, `america;russia;uae` is also an accepted input

I want to take out the first three tokens and make separate properties out of them. In case there are less than 3, then those respective tokens should be `NULL`.

So far I have tried a lot of regular expressions (which I am not comfortable with)

`${testprop}` contains the input string.

i am using the following command

`propertyregex property="testprop1" input="${testprop}" regexp="(.*)(\;.*)*/" select="\1"`

but it is not working. any suggestions for a better regex !!

Comment: `/(?i)\b([\w]{1,2}(?=;))/` Try this regex

Comment: om39a : thanks but sorry. it doesnt match the input.

Comment: Above regex will match any string with less than 3 characters. You can check it out over here http://www.regex101.com/r/kW3vA5

Comment: i am sorry, i should have made it clear that the tokens can be any number of characters and are not limited to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I finally worked out the answer.

Using the following regex,
`([^;]+)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)`

we can get the first 3 string tokens in groups `1`, `2` and `4` respectively. But the group `2` comes with a preceding `;` which can be further removed by applying `\;(.*)` and extracting group `1`.

`property name="inputString" value="russia;uae;germany;africa;"`

`propertyregex property="string1" input="${inputString}" regexp="([^;]+)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)" select="\1"`

`propertyregex property="string2" input="${inputString}" regexp="([^;]+)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)" select="\2"`

`propertyregex property="string3" input="${string2}" regexp="\;(.*)" select="\1"`

`propertyregex property="string4" input="${inputString}" regexp="([^;]+)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)([;]?[^;]*)([;]?)" select="\4"`

This gives you the desired first three tokens in string1, string3 and string4

`string1 = russia`

`string3 = uae`

`string4 = germany`

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to cut down get the first 3 characters if they exist.

`/(?i)\b([\w]{3}(?=[\w]*;))/`

[Verify Here](http://www.regex101.com/r/nF0gX1)

Use this regex to get the string who have value less than 3 characters.

`/(?i)\b([\w]{1,2}(?=;))/`

[Verify Here](http://www.regex101.com/r/kW3vA5)

Comment: but, there can be more than 3 characters in a token. instead of the test string that you using for testing your regex's .. try using the following and see if you can extract the first 3 tokens/groups

"stringa;stringb;stringc;stringd"

from this, try to extract "stringa", "stringb" and "stringc"

Comment: Just to verify what dose this statement from your question mean? `I want to take out the first three and make separate properties out of them. In case there are less than 3, then those respective tokens should be NULL.`

Comment: it means, that for an input string like `"stringa;stringb;stringc;stringd"` i want to create 3 properties, say `prop1`, `prop2` and `prop3` with values `stringa`, `stringb` and `stringc` respectively.
If however, the input string is something like `"stringa;stringb"` then the properties `prop1` and `prop2` will have values `stringa` and `stringb` while `prop3` contains the value `NULL`